# Which is better: calling procedure inside a procedure or executing sql inside a procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, join

I have 3 tables: 
 1. student: {id, name, roll}
 2. subject: {id, name} 
 3. marks: {student_id, subject_id, marks}

I have a procedure which returns all the student and their marks (say getAllMarks() ), i want to create another procedure which returns marks of a given roll no (say getRollMarks(int rollno)). So there are two ways i can create the procedure:
1. write the appropriate SQL to get the result in getRollMarks procedure.
2. call getAllMarks in getRollMarks and then apply where clause on the result returned by getAllMarks. 
Can anyone suggest pros and cons of above two methods? I have 2 Pros of method 2:
1.SQL queries won't be repeated across procedures.
2.If anything is changing in one table, the change will be done at one place/procedure, not in every procedure which is using that table.
PS: The tables are just for example, actually they are bigger tables with many parameters to query. The question can be simplified as **should we write repeated queries in different procedures, or should we use existing procedures with required clause (where, order by, joins etc)?**

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to repeat the query, you should be using a view. Also performance wise it is faster.

Comment: first, i never said i don't want to, I want the solution which is better. second, I gave you one table as an example there can be 10+ tables with 10^6 rows of data and multiple procedures like above two. So creating views for all of them won't be good i guess.

Comment: ok I guess, I miss understood but I it is a pro to have less repetition because of easier maintenance. Performance wise also there is not much difference between calling nested stored procedure or calling it individually http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2011/07/20/will-wrapping-up-code-in-a-reusable-stored-procedure-hurt-performance.aspx

Comment: thanks for the link, it seems the example taken in the link are not good enough to compare the performance of the two, in my case, there are more than 2 tables with more than lakh rows. I think there will be significant performance overhead in 2nd case. Do you think views or temp table can be of help in any way?

Comment: What your stored procedure does is a different beast altogether but the link shows the overhead of nesting stored procedure is minimal.  As for your second question, only indexed views can be faster than stored procedures if done properly. Personally I will use a view if there is no conditional logic involved